# Displaying table of entries in HTML, PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I wanted to create an HTML page which would have a set search criterias. Once the end user selects the criteria, it should show all the records with specific number of records at a time and NEXT link to load remaining records. All this should happen on the same page as where the search criteria is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tutorial.

http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination

If you don't like that one, google for "php pagination". There are tons out there.

As a side note, your question is not specific enough to be answered in a forum format like this. Pagination and reporting interfaces are fairly complex and code heavy, so it's not just a snippet that someone here can easily walk you through. Tutorials are your best bet because they will have all of the sample code you need, and will explain it sufficiently that you can modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I always wanted to add same buttons for each record in the paginations. Can you please let me know how I can do that?

Comment: That would be part of one of those tutorials I pointed you to.